# Locking files on folder with external tools or native components - windows

Tags: .net, file, passwords, locking, data-protection

I'm a software developer, and i've been stuck on this problem for days, i've done so much googling but i found nothing about this....

I'll try to describe this problem as easy as i can.

I have 2 files, "f1" and "f2" into my directory "c:\foo\dir1\"
I want to avoid any possible "change" in those 2 files by any user, but NOT using any encryption. 
Instead of using encryption, when the user opens "f1", i want to pop up something that says to him:

"Hello user! You cannot edit those files this way! You need to do *those things* or entry the password"

Where *those things* are accessibile only from my software, that callbacks the editor of those files, unlocking them at the beginning of editation and re-locking them at the end. 
The possibility of unlocking the files with password is only a way to "emergency-unlock" those files, the user normally does not have it.

So, let's start with the questions:

1) 
Does exist some native function of Windows that provides that mechanism, that i can use with (for instance) a .NET callback? 
I know that the ZIPPING of the folder allows me to set a password, but i don't want to do that.

2) 
If, as i think, the question 1 has no answers... 
Does exist some "external tool" that i can callback into my code that can do this job? Like a "file locker" or similar? 
In case of, i'd obviously prefer something freeware and with "open" license...

I hope i've been clear, despite my inaccurate English language...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any such external tool but if you are building this for your software then you can use following approach:

1. Take data from both the files **F1** and **F2** and serialize it.
2. Export serialized data into some file with some *extension*.(eg. serialized_F1.*extension* and serialized_F2.*extension*)
3. Make sure that file with specified *extension* only opens in your application.
4. Write any protection strategy for DeSerializing the file from your application when any user tries to open these files.

This will achieve following things for you:

1. Files f1 and f2 will only open from your application.
2. Only your application can open these files and you can provide any kind of protection for opening these files.